# linear-gradient not full height of body

Tags: css

My linear-gradient only goes to the bottom of the div.

> **Question** How to make sure the body linear-gradient goes to full height of the page?

**[CODEPEN DEMO](https://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/full/gozjQr/)**

[image]

CSS

```
body {
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #0087e0 50%, #004165 50%, #004165);
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}

.header {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
    background: #F0F0F0;
    min-height: 600px;
}

@media (max-width: 968px) {
    .text-mobile {
        text-align: center !important;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your `html` and `body` height to 100%;

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: that's work fine, but if page has scrolling bar, this is not working anymore when you scroll down the page